# Service restarted at every apt upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, systemd

Everytime I run `apt upgrade` and there is an actual upgrade, a service that I have created gets restarted.
Typically, I get this message

```
┌────┤ Daemons using outdated libraries ├─────┐
│                                             │
│                                             │
│ Which services should be restarted?         │
│                                             │
│    [ ] unattended-upgrades.service          │
│    [*] wildfly.service                      │
│                                             │
│                                             │
│          <Ok>              <Cancel>
```

This seems to be related to needrestart, see output below:

```
$sudo needrestart -u NeedRestart::UI::stdio -r l

Scanning processes...
Scanning candidates...
Scanning linux images...

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

Services to be restarted:
 systemctl restart wildfly.service
```

This is the service configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=WildFly Application Server
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=wildfly
Group=wildfly

StandardOutput=null

ExecStart=/opt/wildfly/wildfly-26.1.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh
ExecReload=/opt/wildfly/wildfly-26.1.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --commands="reload"
ExecStop=/opt/wildfly/wildfly-26.1.1.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --commands="shutdown"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What do I need to change so that the service does not get restarted unnecessarily in the future?

Comment: hard to say - but you described your dependencies very clearly: network-online.target. During update of network components the target will stop.

Comment: @kanehekili Thanks for this. In the end it was unrelated, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to java archives (jar) files in the wildfly temporary deployment folder. This can be seen by running needrestart in verbose mode:

```
sudo needrestart -b -v
```

Since my custom service does not need to be restarted on upgrades, I added a exception by creating a `wildfly.conf` file in `/etc/needrestart/conf.d/`:

```
$nrconf{blacklist_rc} = [
    q(^wildfly) ,
];
```

Note: I got the idea from [a related issue in Tomcat](https://github.com/liske/needrestart/issues/157).